# Efficiently removing consecutive pair duplicates in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, performance, duplicates

I have a bunch of long lists (millions of elements long) that contain a time value and a temperature value (`[time, temperature]`). The lists look like this:

```
mylist = [[1, 72], [2, 75], [3, 74], [4, 75], [5, 74], [6, 75], [7, 79], [8, 71], [9, 79], [10, 71], [11, 75], [12, 74]]
```

What I want to do is get rid of **consecutive pair duplicates**. If a *pair of temperatures* are repeated consecutively, get rid of these duplicate elements (keeping only one).

That wording may be kind of confusing, so I'll provide an example using `mylist`:

`mylist[0]` and `mylist[1]` are consecutive pairs. Same with `mylist[1]` and `mylist[2]`, and so on.

Moving on. Now, look at the temperature value from `mylist`. From `mylist[0]` all the way to `mylist[11]`, the temperature values are:

`72 75 74 75 74 75 79 71 79 71 75 74`

In the above temperature values, you can see that a the pairs `75 74` as well as `79 71` are repeated in a consecutive fashion. What I want to do is just keep one pair, and get rid of the duplicates. So, the output I want is:

```
output = [[1, 72], [2, 75], [3, 74], [6, 75], [7, 79], [8, 71], [11, 75], [12, 74]]
```

Note: elements `[11, 75]` and `[12, 74]` are kept because although they also contain this `75 74` pattern, they aren't repeated consecutively, like from earlier in the list.

---

To try to solve this problem, I searched up and tried a bunch of things. The closest I got was by creating a solution using a `for` loop, where I'd check an element and the previous element (index-1), and then I'd check index-2 and index-3, and if they were determined to have temperature repeats, I'd delete two of the elements. Then, I'd repeat this looking in the forward direction (index+1). It kind of worked, but things got super messy and was extremely slow, and it turned my computer into a portbable heater. So, I was wondering if anyone knows how to efficiently and quickly way to get rid of these consecutive duplicate pairs.

Comment: Can length of the pattern be longer than 2? That is, [72, 75, 74] can be a pattern?

Comment: @GilseungAhn Hello, thanks for your reply! The pattern should just have a length of 2. This is because the temperatures fluctuate between two points often, and I want to get rid of these fluctuations to make the data files much smaller. Does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that I have understood the requirement correctly, the code below does the job.

```
mylist = [[1, 72], [2, 75], [3, 74], [4, 75], [5, 74], [6, 75], [7, 79], [8, 71], [9, 79], [10, 71], [11, 75], [12, 74]]

n = len(mylist)
index = 0
output_list = []

# We need at least four elements to check if there is a duplicate pair.
while index + 4 <= n:
    sub_list = mylist[index: index + 4]

    if sub_list[0][1] == sub_list[2][1] and sub_list[1][1] == sub_list[3][1]:
        print('Duplicate found')
        # Drop the second one.
        output_list.append(sub_list[0])
        output_list.append(sub_list[1])
        index += 4
    else:
        # We add only the first element as the there can be a potential duplicate that can be found later on when we consider the next element.
        output_list.append(sub_list[0])
        index += 1

# Append the remaining elements if any exist.
output_list.extend(mylist[index:])


print(output_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `collections.deque`:

```
from collections import deque

mylist = [[1, 72], [2, 75], [3, 74], [4, 75], [5, 74], [6, 75], [7, 79], [8, 71], [9, 79], [10, 71], [11, 75], [12, 74]]

def generate(lst):
    d = deque(maxlen=4)
    for v in lst:
        d.append(v)
        if len(d)==4:
            if d[0][1] == d[2][1] and d[1][1] == d[3][1]:
                d.pop()
                d.pop()
            else:
                yield d.popleft()

    yield from d # yield the rest of deque


out = [*generate(mylist)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 72], [2, 75], [3, 74], [6, 75], [7, 79], [8, 71], [11, 75], [12, 74]]
```

Benchmark (using 10_000_000 elements):

```
import random
from timeit import timeit

mylist = []
for i in range(10_000_000):
    mylist.append([i, random.randint(50, 100)])

def f1():
    return [*generate(mylist)]

t1 = timeit(lambda: f1(), number=1)
print(t1)
```

Prints on my machine (AMD 2400G, Python 3.8):

```
3.2782217629719526
```

Comment: +1 for a great answer! Thanks again for your help, Andrej. Your's and Srikant's answers both seem to work quite efficiently for my data, and it's great that it doesn't use any 3rd party libraries. I wish I could mark both as "Accepted". I've just marked Srikant's as "Best", simply because he has less points - I hope you don't mind. Again, I really appreciate your answer - it is an excellent solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use `collection.Counters` and `numpy`.

Try this code.

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

def remove_consecutive_pair_duplicate(L):
    temperature = np.array(L, dtype = str)[:, 1]
    l = 2 # length of pattern       
    pattern_with_length_l = Counter('-'.join(temperature[i:i+l]) for i in range(len(temperature) - l))

    set_of_patterns = []
    for (key, val) in pattern_with_length_l.items():
        left, right = key.split('-')        
        if val >= 2 and right + '-' + left not in set_of_patterns:
            set_of_patterns.append(key)

    removed_index = []
    for pattern in set_of_patterns:
        matched_index = [[i, i+1] for i in range(len(temperature) - l) if '-'.join(temperature[i:i+2]) == pattern]
        for ind in matched_index[1:]:
            removed_index.append(ind[0])
            removed_index.append(ind[1])

    survived_ind = list(set(list(range(len(L)))) - set(removed_index))
    return np.array(L)[survived_ind].tolist()

print(remove_consecutive_pair_duplicate(mylist))
```

The result is as follows.

```
[[1, 72], [2, 75], [3, 74], [6, 75], [7, 79], [8, 71], [11, 75], [12, 74]]
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer!! However, it seems that Andrej's solution is the fastest. Great answer, nontheless!